# #NAME? when referencing cell in different worksheet

Tags: libreoffice-calc

I'm using libre calculator.  I just want to reference a cell in another worksheet in the same workbook, but I get #NAME? showing up.   I know in the past, I've had this problem before, but never figured out how to solve it.  Here's what I did.

On `sheet1`, I have a cell`B1` which has the value `1999`.  On `sheet2`, I typed into `A1` the value `='sheet1'!B1`.  Then the sheet2 A1 cell shows `#NAME?`.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the first I've run into this (recent Excel immigrant and no need yet for multiple sheets in Calc), but I replicated your problem.  Instead of typing in the cell reference, I pointed to it to see what would get stored.  This is what I got:

```
=Sheet1.B1
```

No quotes (which I thought might be your issue).  However, apparently, LibreOffice Calc uses a period instead of an exclamation point to delimit the sheet name.  I checked the help, and sure enough, that's the format.

The period is the Calc default, but there is a menu setting (it's moved around a bit in different versions), that lets you use Excel address formatting.  Currently it's in `Tools | Options | LibreOffice Calc | Formula`.  Under `Formula Syntax`, choose `Excel A1`.  As in Excel, the exclamation point is used as the delimiter with that setting.

Answer (score 0):

Ok that's weird.  So to fix the problem, I saved the file.  Then I closed the file. Then I re-opened the file.  Libre Calculator automatically converted my `='sheet1'!B1` to `=$Sheet1.B1`, and now it shows the value of sheet 1 b1.  I have no idea why I have to save and re-open file just to get this to work.